# when i run it, it show Exception in Application constructor

Tags: java, authentication, javafx

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public abstract class login extends Application
{
    Stage window;
    public static void main(String arvg[])
    {
        launch(arvg);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        window= primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Login");

        GridPane grid=new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        grid.setVgap(8);
        grid.setHgap(8);

        //Label1
        Label lbl1=new Label("User Name");
        GridPane.setConstraints(lbl1,0,0);

        //label2
        Label lbl2=new Label("Password");
        GridPane.setConstraints(lbl2,0,1);

        //userinput
        TextField username=new TextField();
        username.setPromptText("UserName");
        GridPane.setConstraints(username,1,0);

        //Password
       TextField password=new TextField();
        password.setPromptText("Password");
        GridPane.setConstraints(password,1,1);

        //login
        Button button=new Button("Log In");
        GridPane.setConstraints(button,0,2);

        grid.getChildren().addAll(lbl1,lbl2,username,password,button);
        Scene s=new Scene(grid,300,200);
        window.setScene(s);
        window.show();

    }
}
```

This is a login page.When i try to run it, it show Exception in Application constructor and a lot of error like Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class login
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
I got no idea what is the problem. So any one can explain or help me fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you make the class abstract? The application will not be able to create an object from the class if it is abstract. Remove the `abstract` keyword from your class definition.